# Не могу выявить ошибку в коде расчета матрицы

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день, товарищи программисты, не могу понять где у меня ошибка в коде, нужно чтобы первый элемент строки матрицы был равен номеру строки, второй элемент равен первому(k=j-1), и следующие элементы суммируют предыдущие помогите пожалуйста, я уже опробовал многое, не приходит в голову исправление кода. Работаю в WindowsForm[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrica.RowCount; i++)     
            for (int j = 0; j < Matrica.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                if (j > 1)      
                {                                       
                    matr[i, j] = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < j - 1; k++)
                        matr[i, j] += matr[i, k];
                }                   
                else     
                        matr[i, j]= i;
```

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы не написать код как можно ближе к формуле?

```
for (int i = 0; i < Matrica.RowCount; i++)     
    for (int j = 0; j < Matrica.ColumnCount; j++)
    {
        if(j==0)
        {
            matr[i, j] = i+1;
        }
        else 
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k<j; k++) 
                sum += matr[i, k];
            matr[i, j] = sum;
        }
    }
```

В Вашем коде проблема с индексами, в C# они идут с нуля, из-за этого возникают ошибки на единицу.

Другая проблема что таблица у Вас отображается наоборот: строки и столбцы перепутаны местами. Это уже нужно разбираться с кодом в Windows Forms (или что это?).